# Issue with Jama's Eigenvalue decomposition function

Tags: java, jama, eigenvector

I am getting a wrong eigen-vector (also checked by running multiple times to be sure) when i am using `matrix.eig()`.  The matrix is:

```
1.2290 1.2168 2.8760 2.6370 2.2949 2.6402
1.2168 0.9476 2.5179 2.1737 1.9795 2.2828
2.8760 2.5179 8.8114 8.6530 7.3910 8.1058
2.6370 2.1737 8.6530 7.6366 6.9503 7.6743
2.2949 1.9795 7.3910 6.9503 6.2722 7.3441 
2.6402 2.2828 8.1058 7.6743 7.3441 7.6870
```

The function returns the eigen vectors:

```
-0.1698  0.6764  0.1442 -0.6929 -0.1069  0.0365
-0.1460  0.6478  0.1926  0.6898  0.0483 -0.2094
-0.5239  0.0780 -0.5236  0.1621 -0.2244  0.6072
-0.4906 -0.0758 -0.4573 -0.1279  0.2842 -0.6688
-0.4428 -0.2770  0.4307  0.0226 -0.6959 -0.2383
-0.4884 -0.1852  0.5228 -0.0312  0.6089  0.2865
```

Matlab gives the following eigen-vector for the same input:

```
0.1698 -0.6762 -0.1439  0.6931  0.1069  0.0365
0.1460 -0.6481 -0.1926 -0.6895 -0.0483 -0.2094
0.5237 -0.0780  0.5233 -0.1622  0.2238  0.6077
0.4907  0.0758  0.4577  0.1278 -0.2840 -0.6686
0.4425  0.2766 -0.4298 -0.0227  0.6968 -0.2384
0.4888  0.1854 -0.5236  0.0313 -0.6082  0.2857
```

The eigen-values for matlab and jama are matching but eigen-vectors the first 5 columns are reversed in sign and only the last column is accurate.

Is there any issue on the kind of input that `Jama.Matrix.EigenvalueDecomposition.eig()`
accepts or any other problem with the same? Please tell me how i can fix the error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no error here, both results are correct - as is any other scalar times the eigen vectors.

There are an infinite number of eigen vectors that work - its just convention that most software programs report the vectors that have length of one.  That Jama reports eigen vectors equal to -1 times those of Matlab is probably just an artifact of the algorithm they used.

Comment: please see carefully.... it is not scalar times another eigen vector all the columns except last have been inverted in sign..
last column for both is same... which is incorrect.

Comment: As I understand the conventions used for the result, each column is an eigenvector. So *one* of those has not been flipped in sign. Which makes each column still a valid eigenvector of norm 1. Where is the problem?

Comment: So, each of the eigen vectos may be flipped in sign and it's still safe. Then, the my doubt is cleared. Thanks..

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been tearing my hair out trying to work out why I was getting flipped signs in Jama compared to Matlab. nice to know that it's irrelevant to the outcome

Answer (score 1):

For a given matrix, the eigenvalues are unique, whose number equals the dimension of the matrix if plurality is considered. While the corresponding eigenvalues might be different because the vectors can scale according to a certain direction. In your post results, both JAVA and Matlab versions are correct.

Also, you could check the D matrix, where the eigenvalues come from. You could find they are the same.